# shutil.copyfile(src, dir, ...) PermissionError

Tags: python

Whenever I run this code:

```
for file in range(0, len(contents)):
    shutil.copyfile(contents[file], backupdir)
```

('contents' is a tuple of the file directories),
it returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:\Pycharm\PyDRS\main.py", line 401, in <module>
    main()
  File "a:\Pycharm\PyDRS\main.py", line 253, in main
    shutil.copyfile(contents[file], backupdir)
  File "C:\Users\Luke_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:'
```

I've ran the program in Administrator: Windows Powershell like this:

```
python A:\Pycharm\PyDRS\main.py
```

though I reckon it's irrelevant.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Feel free to ask me about other information.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What are the actual values of the `copyfile` arguments?

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile), `dst` should be a complete target file name, not a folder.

Comment: @gshpychka the arguments (for the first instance) would be copyfile('A:\Test\file.txt', 'E:'), and none of the files are a folder. Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Like I said above, the value of the `dst` argument has to be the complete target file name, and yours is `E:`, which is not a file name.

Comment: @gshpychka Regarding your comment, sorry for incorrectly interpreting it. The code is working now, I understand what you mean as in 'not a folder'. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile), `dst` should be a complete target file name, not a folder. You are passing `E:`, which is a folder, not a target file name.